# Google map integration by php

Tags: php, google-maps, geocoding

I have all info City name,state,Country,street name,house number and zip code.Can i locate this in Google map.How will i do? From where i can get API for google for such problems?

Answer (score 2):

Here the source for all the APIs built off of Google maps with documentation.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to get the lat/lng for your addresses. You do this with google's geocoder api

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Then you can add them to the map with their map api

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get latitude and longitude using City name,state,Country,street name,house number and zip code using javascript, store that latitude and longitude in database or as you want and using that latitude and longitude you can show that location in google map.